# How to pass custom coordinates to map box navigation launcher?

Tags: android, navigation, maps, mapbox, mapbox-android

Mapbox provides good Navigation SDK for Android, and what I have been trying to do is pass custom lat and lng's to mapbox navigation launcher. But its taking current user location and i would like to pass the custom coordinates .  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a `DirectionsRoute` and then eventually [give it to the `NavigationLauncherOptions.Builder`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/android/navigation/testapp/activity/navigationui/NavigationLauncherActivity.java#L349).

[You can build a route with a custom origin instead of the device location](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/android/navigation/testapp/activity/navigationui/NavigationLauncherActivity.java#L258).

[Also, you can add custom waypoints](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/android/navigation/testapp/activity/navigationui/NavigationLauncherActivity.java#L263).

Create a waypoint via the `Point` class. `Point wayPoint = Point.fromLngLat(longCoordinate, latCoordinate);`

[Once you get the route from the response](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/android/navigation/testapp/activity/navigationui/NavigationLauncherActivity.java#L272), you can eventually give it to the options builder before [starting the NavigationLauncher](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/android/navigation/testapp/activity/navigationui/NavigationLauncherActivity.java#L365).